# How to include referenced external assembly into my wsp

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I've referenced [SPMeta2](https://github.com/SubPointSolutions/spmeta2) dlls into several of my solutions and I'm wondering if there is a way to add them to my wsp. "Copy to local" adds them to the output folder, but they're not included into the wsp.

I could manually add them to the package, but since there're monthly releases, I would have to update the reference each month again.

Is there an other way than to add those assemblies to GAC?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get them packaged in your WSP by opening the `Package.package` file in your VS project, click on the "Advanced" tab, click the "Add" button and choose "Add Existing Assembly."

Then for the "source path" just click on the ellipses button and browse to where the assembly is.

Comment: And after selection the dll you would choose GAC or Web Application? If I choose GAC it's not only added to the wsp but also directly deployed to GAC.

Comment: Also since NuGet adds new folders for each new version I would have to manually update the path to the current assembly each time I update it.